# How to detect out of distribution samples while working with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, outliers

For proper inference in real-world applications, detecting samples which are out of data distribution used for training the ML model, is indispensable.

Probability Thresholding doesn't seem a good option as most DNNs are generally overconfident even for out of distribution samples.

I have found a few papers which talk about `out-of-distribution-detection` but Tensorflow doesn't seem to have an inbuilt implementation for any of them.

As this seems to be a common scenario for any ML model deployed for real world application, I was wondering if there is a way to find `out of distribution samples` before making an inference (in TensorFlow or TFLite, given a trained CNN model in .pb or .tflite graph file format)?